# share connectionstrings with multiple projects in same solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-config, connection-string, config, configsource

I have multiple projects in the same solution. I would like them to share the same connectionStrings so that I don't have to change the this in multiple places.

In my web configs I have

```
<connectionStrings  configSource="bin/connectionStrings.config" />
```

and then I have added a file as a link to my "connectionsStrings.config" which sits at the solution level.

I have changed the properties so that the "Copy to Output Directory" is "Copy always" and the "Build Action" is "Content"

But I get the following error:

```
 The configSource attribute must be a relative physical path, so the '/' character is not allowed.
```

I am not sure how to get around this issue, any help would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this by changing

```
<connectionStrings  configSource="bin/connectionStrings.config" />
```

to

```
<connectionStrings  configSource="bin\connectionStrings.config" />
```

:/

Comment: Just a suggestion: I hope you choose a better place for your connectionStrings.config file as the bin folder normally contains build output and is not a very intuitive place for this.